# clearInterval() function is not working, cannot figure out why..?

Tags: javascript, clearinterval

I've try to figure out why my `clearInterval()` function is not working. After numerous attempts to fix, asking on Stack Overflow for expert's advice.

Also, instead of functioning as `clearInterval()`, it actually speeds up when I press 'stop' button. I wonder why that is...?

**TLDR:**
*Created multiple `<div>` squares which changes color randomly. 
Used interval function to set the speed of color changing.
However, stopping the function is not working but rather speeds it up.*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <style>
    .squre {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      border: 1px black solid;
    }
    
    button:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div id='wrapper'>
    <div class='squre'></div>
    <div class='squre'></div>
    <div class='squre'></div>
    <div class='squre'></div>
    <div class='squre'></div>
    <div class='squre'></div>
    <div class='squre'></div>
    <div class='squre'></div>
  </div>

  <button onclick='interval()'>Change Color!</button>
  <button onclick='stopChange()' id='stop'>Stop This!</button>

  <script>
    function interval() {
      const mv = setInterval(colorChange, 100);
    }

    function stopChange() {
      clearInterval(mv);
    }

    function colorChange() {
      var cc = document.getElementsByClassName('squre');
      var ccStop = document.querySelector('#stop');
      var i;

      for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
        if (x == 1) {
          cc[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        } else if (x == 1) {
          cc[i].style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
        } else if (x == 2) {
          cc[i].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
        } else if (x == 3) {
          cc[i].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        } else if (x == 4) {
          cc[i].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
        } else if (x == 5) {
          cc[i].style.backgroundColor = 'purple';
        } else if (x == 6) {
          cc[i].style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
        } else if (x == 7) {
          cc[i].style.backgroundColor = 'black';
        } else if (x == 8) {
          cc[i].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        } else if (x == 9) {
          cc[i].style.backgroundColor = 'white';
        } else if (x == 10) {
          cc[i].style.backgroundColor = 'brown';
        } else if (x == 0) {
          cc[i].style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';
        } else {
          alert('error');
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Instead of relying on globals, you could use either encapsulation or function parameters.  In OOP, mv would live inside a class, and start/stop would be methods. For functional programming, just pass in the interval (mv) that stopChange should be acting upon instead of relying on a variable defined elsewhere: ex. stopChange(mv);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first  you have to declare  mv outside of the function to let other functions access it
you set it to const
  `var mv;`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <style>
    .squre {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      border: 1px black solid;
    }
    
    button:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div id='wrapper'>
    <div class='squre'></div>
    <div class='squre'></div>
    <div class='squre'></div>
    <div class='squre'></div>
    <div class='squre'></div>
    <div class='squre'></div>
    <div class='squre'></div>
    <div class='squre'></div>
    <div class='squre'></div>
    <div class='squre'></div>
    <div class='squre'></div>
  </div>

  <button onclick='interval()'>Change Color!</button>
  <button onclick='stopChange()' id='stop'>Stop This!</button>

  <script>
    var mv;

    function interval() {
      mv = setInterval(colorChange, 100);
    }

    function stopChange() {
      clearInterval(mv);
    }

    function colorChange() {
      var cc = document.getElementsByClassName('squre');
      var ccStop = document.querySelector('#stop');
      var i;

      for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
        if (x == 1) {
          cc[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        } else if (x == 1) {
          cc[i].style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
        } else if (x == 2) {
          cc[i].style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
        } else if (x == 3) {
          cc[i].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        } else if (x == 4) {
          cc[i].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
        } else if (x == 5) {
          cc[i].style.backgroundColor = 'purple';
        } else if (x == 6) {
          cc[i].style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
        } else if (x == 7) {
          cc[i].style.backgroundColor = 'black';
        } else if (x == 8) {
          cc[i].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        } else if (x == 9) {
          cc[i].style.backgroundColor = 'white';
        } else if (x == 10) {
          cc[i].style.backgroundColor = 'brown';
        } else if (x == 0) {
          cc[i].style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';
        } else {
          alert('error');
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make `mv` global. Otherwise the variable is only local and the value is not available out of the scope of the function.

```
var mv; // global, not const

function interval() {
    mv = setInterval(colorChange, 100);
}

function stopChange() {
    clearInterval(mv);
}
```